# How can I solve "safari can't establish secure connection to the server localhost"

Tags: localhost

[image: screenshot]

I have attempted to create an offline copy of my website using MAMP on localhost port 8888. I have changed all the database urls and updated the wp config file, however, when I try to load the site I get this error.

Http:// is forcing https://

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mamp local site not working in Chrome and Safari but Firefox works (High Sierra)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245091/mamp-local-site-not-working-in-chrome-and-safari-but-firefox-works-high-sierra)

Comment: Not in the slightest as I don't understand it. I'm using the free MAMP does this make a difference?